# Dump current stack in GNAT compiled Ada?

Tags: stack, stack-trace, trace, ada, gnat

In java I use this method sometimes to see where I am in the current stack:

[http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#dumpStack()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#dumpStack%28%29)

I am new to the Ada world, but am curious if there is anything similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viewing the traceback stack is compiler-specific. The GNAT Ada compiler provides some packages to manage this (in conjunction with some compile/link options). See the [Stack Traceback](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/gnat_and_program_execution.html#stack-traceback) section of the GNAT User's Guide for information and examples.

Comment: Make sure you have the debug symbols compiled in (-g). Without them, you'll only get addresses instead of function names.

Comment: FYI, there is a bug in GNAT library which causes a crash when you use symbolic traceback (at least on Ubuntu, gcc 4.4).  You will find a simple fix at http://blog.vacs.fr/index.php?post/2010/09/19/How-to-fix-GNAT-symbolic-traceback-crash-on-Ubuntu.  Beware that symbolic traceback can be very slow as it could rely on an external program 'addr2line' (for gcc 4.4 at least).