# Get call stack in string format

Tags: ada

Is there a way to print call stack when printing a message ?

I have a procedure:

```
procedure DoSomething (myParameter : in MyType)
is
  isOk : Boolean := False;
begin
  isOk := FunctionReturningFalseWhenError(myParameter);
  if not isOk
  then
    MyDisplayFunction(GNAT.Source_Info.File & ":" & Positive'Image(GNAT.Source_Info.Line) & ": Error with DoSomething");
  end if;
end DoSomething;
```

This procedure is called many times and I want to have more information to print (like call stack).

Comment: Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5572370/40851)? - 2 questions down from yours (in my browser, anyway)

Comment: Any thoughts about creating a standard API package that does this?   VHDL-2019 (hardware child of Ada), has an package in our standard library (std.env) that provides access to this information - breaking us free of tool dependent non-sense.